# Sending byte[] or URL for Image

Tags: android, performance, sockets, byte, picasso

I'm creating an Android app. For this I created a recyclerview, which gets filled by images and texts. Until now I've got the images from my server with sockets and byte[]. In my app I converted this to bitmaps. But that has not the best performance. Should I get the images with Picasso and URL? Has this a better performance?

Comment: `I've got the images from my server with sockets and byte[]. In my app I converted this to bitmaps. But that has not the best performance`. There is no reason that performance would not be good. Where is the bottleneck in your opinion?

Comment: @greenapps I'm calculating and setting the image also "normal" and not with something like Picasso. I think this could also take much performance.

Comment: I already understood that you did not use Picasso or another library. `I think this could also take much performance` What do you mean? 'take performance'? Does it take much time you mean? Again: I see no reason that if you do all yourself that performance would be worse.

Comment: @greenapps The RV is laggy when I try to scroll. Perhaps I do to much stuff on the UI-Thread.

Comment: No idea. Only you know.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in the android or iOS app from the API's we have to get the image url. By using image loader library's we will load that data.

For the android most of the developers prefer universal image loader or picasso for loading their images.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to rely on image loader library like Picasso or UniversalIL as these libraries will manage caching, downsampling and even error handling. Android is very sensitive about bitmap. Without proper management, there will be a lot of exception including the infamous one: BitmapOutOfMemory.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 locations where images are stored. Their comparison on Memory space availability and Accessibility speed is given below:

1. Server (Memory Space is HIGH but Accessibility is SLOW)
2. Hard Disk on Mobile (Memory Space is MEDIUM and Accessibility is MEDIUM)
3. Heap Memory (Memory Space is LOW and Accessibility is FAST)

We need to create a balance among above 3 locations for optimum utilization of accessibility and memory space.

Use any lazy loading library like picasso or UIL and you don't have to worry about any of these points.It will handle everything itself :)